# How to redirect depending of the role with Grails Acegi on weblogic

Tags: grails, weblogic, spring-security

in my index.gsp, I have this :

```
<g:ifAnyGranted role="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY">
  <% response.sendRedirect("login/auth"); %>
</g:ifAnyGranted>
<g:ifAnyGranted role="ROLE_ADMIN">
  <% response.sendRedirect("admin/tasks"); %>
</g:ifAnyGranted>
<g:ifAnyGranted role="ROLE_VIEWER_I, ROLE_VIEWER_E">
  <% response.sendRedirect("items/list"); %>
</g:ifAnyGranted>
```

If I run it on tomcat, that's work fine.

But after a deployment on weblogic 11g, it's not working.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend doing this in the controller, not the view.

```
class SomeController {   
   def springSecurityService   
   def someAction = {
      if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
         response.sendRedirect(...)
      }
      else {
         response.sendRedirect(...)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes It's my new implementation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very strange. I added this implementation but now it is not working on weblogic. I created another topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190651/grails-weblogic-and-redirection-on-root-seems-not-working 
Could you help me again ?