# Grails, Weblogic and redirection on root "/" seems not working

Tags: grails, weblogic

I configured my grails application with an root path like this (in UrlMapping):

```
"/"{
    controller="mycontroller"
    action="myaction"
 }
```

in mycontroller.myaction, depending of the role, I redirect to the right action :

```
def link 
if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_ADMIN") link = g.createLink(action:      "action1", controller:"controller")
else if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAnyGranted("ROLE_ADMIN") link = g.createLink(action: "action2", controller:"controller") 
else ...ANONYMOUS... {
  link = g.creatLink(action:"public", controller:"mycontroller")
}
redirect (url:link)
```

With embedded grails server, it's working fine but with **weblogic** it redirect on the index.gsp.

Why ?

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](http://grailsframework.blogspot.com/2008/05/redirecting-from-indexgsp.html)

- I created a taglib.
- I rename the mapping on "/" to "/redirect" in
  UrlMapping
- I call the taglib in GSP.