# Grails: what are the main issues (and his solutions) when deploying in weblogic?

Tags: grails, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy my grails application (*.war) in a weblogic server.
But now I'm getting error:

> "/index.gsp" not found.

While I run to solve this I'm think what more problems can happen when someone change deploy from Apache Tomcat to Oracle Weblogic.

Anybody have a list of commons problems/solutions to share?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of common problems with different application servers and how to deal with these problems can already be found in the FAQ on the Grails community page.

- [http://www.grails.org/FAQ#Application Servers](http://www.grails.org/FAQ#Application%20Servers)
- [http://www.grails.org/Deployment#Weblogic 11g](http://www.grails.org/Deployment#Weblogic%2011g)

Comment: Correct! That was a more general answer to your question regarding a list of common problems and solutions. I added a second resource that has some hints for deployments on WebLogic.

Comment: Is [my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190651/grails-weblogic-and-redirection-on-root-seems-not-working) should be concerned ? So I have an index.gsp and my controller redirect to it instead of "/"

Comment: Yes, I solved, I need to do 2 things: 
a) use a exploded deploy (unziped)
b) put a COPY o GSPs INSIDE deploy folder.

Comment: Old WIKI pages are no longer available because they contained out of date and out-dated information. I have generated Asiidoc documents with the old contents https://github.com/grails-samples/grails_old_wiki/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/deployment.adoc  https://github.com/grails-samples/grails_old_wiki/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/faq.adoc